# Apache with Ruby - Gems Issue

Tags: ruby, apache, macos

I have this working on Ubuntu fine, but I can't get it to work on Mac OS-X 10.6.7.

My Apache config file is edited so that it runs any `.rb` files. The ruby script I'm using has `require 'rubygems'` in there.

On Ubuntu, I added `SetEnv RUBYOPT rubygems` in my Apache config file so I don't even need to use `require 'rubygems'`. On my Mac, even when I require rubygems, it can't load the gems.

In IRB, it loads the gems fine, and I can run the script from the command line OK.

My script is at /Library/WebServer/Documents

Apache error log says -

```
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/utils/date.rb:57: undefined method `deprecate' for DBI::Date:Class (NoMethodError)
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] \tfrom /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] \tfrom /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] \tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/utils.rb:56
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] \tfrom /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] \tfrom /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] \tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:50
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] \tfrom /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `gem_original_require'
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] \tfrom /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `require'
[Mon May 23 18:56:40 2011] [error] [client ::1] \tfrom /Library/WebServer/Documents/ruby_file.rb:6
```

I thought that adding `require 'rubygems'` meant that the gem paths would be loaded. Anyone know why Apache can't load the gems?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by not putting `require 'dbi'` in my script. Using `require 'sqlite3'` is enough.